# unable to laravel gulp command

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

when running laravel gulp command getting these errors
[image]

here is my app.less file path

```
   C:\xampp\htdocs\roqstar\resources\assets\less\app.less

here is the app.less file data


@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap-less/bootstrap/bootstrap";
```

and i have this file existing

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\roqstar\node_modules\bootstrap-less\bootstrap\bootstrap.less
```

dont know why still not finding the bootstrap.less file

Comment: Have you done an npm install?

Comment: yes i have done

Answer (score 0):

Try `@import "node_modules/bootstrap-less/bootstrap/bootstrap";`